# Convertir caracteres especiales en Python 2.7 para fichero xml

Tags: python, unicode

Tengo una serie de strings como el siguiente:

> "Programa Directrices de Gesti\xc3\xb3n Tur\xc3\xadstica"

Que debo almacenar en un fichero xml por ejemplo:

```
<content><![CDATA[Programa Directrices de Gestión Turística]]></content>
```

Uso este código:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

dato_cdata = doc.createCDATASection(texto)
cdv = doc.createElement(etiqueta)
cdv.appendChild(dato_cdata)
root.appendChild(cdv)
doc.appendChild(root)
```

Pero lo almacena:

```
<content><![CDATA["Programa Directrices de Gesti\xc3\xb3n Tur\xc3\xadstica]]></content>
```

¿Cómo hago para convertirlo?

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
texto = "Programa Directrices de Gesti\xc3\xb3n Tur\xc3\xadstica"
print texto.decode("utf-8")
```

tu resultado seria:

```
Programa Directrices de Gestión Turística
```

Para mayor informacion acude a la documentacion:

[decode Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_decode.htm)

Espero te ayude..!!

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario Diego Avila pero eso sale así porque print maneja la codificación para la salida por pantalla.  Lo que necesito es almacenarlo en un fichero xml.  Probá en el intérprete lo siguiente   ' >>> texto = "Programa Directrices de Gesti\xc3\xb3n Tur\xc3\xadstica"
>>> texto
'Programa Directrices de Gesti\xc3\xb3n Tur\xc3\xadstica'
>>>'